# How to create an opportunity using JSON and PHP?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create an oppurtunity in CRM but I'm unable to do it. I'm very new to this and I din't find any reference for PHP using JSON. Please help with a sample data or reference links. This is the error am getting.

> Error processing request stream. The request should be a valid top-level resource object.

Comment: What is the actual code you're executing?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the organization service using any language as long as they can handle REST based web services, I guess.

As a side note, if you intend to work with Dynamics CRM, you'll probably want to skip PHP and transfer more into C# and JS. Sooner or later (i.e. sooner), you'll be building plugins (that's C#) and customizations of the client-side (that's JS).

I may get my head bitten of for this but I don't think that PHP can be used to work towards CRM very effectively.

Having said that, I can think of a few scenarios where PHP might be a better choice but being a true MS slave (our offices in Stockholm are in fact **right above** Microsoft's. We're on the top floor of MS building here.